# Apt-get and aptitude not working in Ubuntu 9.04 KVM environment

Tags: ubuntu, apt, kvm-virtualization

I don't seem to get apt to work on a KVM in a Ubuntu 9.04 box. The virtual machine is an Ubuntu server.

Network does seem to work (I can ping and attempt ssh connections, for instance), but running apt-get update just gives "E: Method http has died unexpectedly!" when it tries to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security Release.gpg.

Comment: Much as I appreciate you dumping this at serverfault, you'd probably do well by sending it to the kvm-devel mailinglist and / or the kvm bugzilla as well. Sounds like a serious issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first step is to run:

```
# strace -efile,network -f apt-get update
```

And see what happens when it dies.

Comment: strace is not installed, how do I get it without apt-get in a terminal window?

Comment: go to http://packages.ubuntu.com, find the package, download it by hand and then run dpkg -i strace_1.2.3-4_amd64.deb